# How do I resize without losing quality?

Tags: mesh, scale

I am making character for my game in Unreal Engine. I have just finished the entire character (including animations and UV Mapping) and it has come to my attention that I will need to change the unit scale to 0.001. This is an issue because my mesh's dimensions have shrunk. I went to resize my image to find that the mesh has gone a bit weird and I think it's because of a loss of quality. Does anyone know a fix for this? 
Thanks
Liam

Comment: what do you mean by a bit weird?

Comment: Here is an image showing my problem after scaling: https://ibb.co/Chntwt9